# Writing a command line utility in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to write a small command line utility in ruby and distribute it as a gem. I know that once installed, certain gems like Guard, Sass and Thor can be run by themselves from the command line.

What do I need to specify in my gemspec in order to have a gem available like a binary.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Guard/Sass/Thor source? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
  ...
  s.executable = 'name_of_executable'
  ...
end
```

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20